# SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: When product in more than one category - Magento

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento

I've been battling with this for a while.

I get a cardinality violation when adding a product to cart that is in more than one catergory.

SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1241 Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Anybody come across this?

Comment: did you do a google search? http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/6067/

Comment: Yes. It doesn't work. At least not on 1.4.0.1

Comment: As I understand, you use some custom theme, right? Btw, why you don't wish to update to 1.5?

Answer (score 2):

I was getting `SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1241 Operand should contain 1 column(s)`

I was trying to delete some data in my controller's massDeleteAction

```
foreach ($categoryIds as $categoryId) {
                $category = Mage::getModel('look/category')->load($categoryIds);
                $category->delete();
         }
```

Notice the line

```
 $category = Mage::getModel('look/category')->load($categoryIds);
```

After changing the code to

```
foreach ($categoryIds as $categoryId) {
             $category = Mage::getModel('look/category')->load($categoryId);
             $category->delete();
       }
```

Problem resolved